# Postgresql 9.5 Syntax error

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

I perform the same sql scripts on two server with different postgres versions. The first one has postgres 9.4.4 (this works fine) and the other one 9.5 (this throws an exception) installed.

```
UPDATE archived_invoice SET encrypted_xml 
= encrypt(xml::bytea, 'MySuperSecretKey'::bytea, 'aes-ecb/pad:pkcs')
```

The exception:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type bytea
SQL Status:22P02
```

Are there any differences between these two postgresql versions?

Comment: Possibly you have `standard_conforming_strings` differing between systems, which leads to different interpretation of backslashes. Anyway you should use the `convert_to()` function to get bytes from text, as opposed to the cast to bytea. A cast does interpretation of escape sequences, which is completely off base here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PostgreSQL will throw an `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bytea` at you if the `text` you're casting into a `bytea` contains an invalid escape sequence:

```
# select '\i is not a valid escape sequence'::bytea;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bytea
LINE 1: select '\i is not a valid escape sequence'::bytea;
```

I'm guessing your "xml" column contains or may contain some backslashes. This is fine for XML and `text` columns, but presents an issue when casting to `bytea`.

You will need to escape the backslashes:

```
UPDATE archived_invoice SET encrypted_xml 
= encrypt(
    replace(xml, '\', '\\')::bytea,
    'MySuperSecretKey'::bytea,
    'aes-ecb/pad:pkcs'
)
```

Comment: It works, thx! This is really strange. My script is working on windows but not on ubuntu. Why is this a problem?